# Problem with multiple prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Here's the issue. I have a prepared statement, like this:

```
$select_something = $db->stmt_init();
$select_something->prepare ("
SELECT whatever 
FROM table
");
$select_something->execute();
$select_something->bind_result($whatever);
```

When alone - it works. When I add another one after it's execution it also works.
But when I try to just first prepare them both:

```
$select_something = $db->stmt_init();
$select_something->prepare ("
SELECT whatever 
FROM table
");
```

and execute them later on:

```
$select_something->execute();
$select_something->bind_result($whatever);
```

the first statement gets executed, and the second one throws this error for both lines above:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute() [mysqli-stmt.execute]: invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt

Note, statements are named differently ($select_something and $select_something_else), I just thought it's needless to repeat the code.

Comment: Please make [code samples complete](http://sscce.org/) as well as concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the mysqli extension has been replaced by [PDO](http://php.net/PDO), which is simpler to use and better behaved. You should use it rather than mysqli. If you need a PDO tutorial, try "[Writing MySQL Scripts with PHP and PDO](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html)". Even if you switch, you may still wish to figure out what is going wrong, in which case read on.

That particular error simply means you're not dealing with a `mysqli_stmt` in `$select_something` or `$select_something_else`. Functions in many extensions (especially DB extensions) return `false` when they fail, rather than a resource or object. That's probably what's happening here. Follow proper error handling procedure by testing the return value of functions that could fail. Use [`mysqli::error`](http://php.net/mysqli.error) to get a description of why a MySQLi function/method is failing.

You may be running across a limitation of mysqli and the MySQL driver: the lower level [`mysql_use_result()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-use-result.html) or [`mysql_store_result()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-store-result.html) must be called on results before they can be used. By default, `mysqli_stmt::execute` probably calls `mysql_use_result`, which means the old result must be [closed before a new query is run](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commands-out-of-sync.html) (which is mentioned in the documentation for [`mysqli::query()`](http://php.net/mysqli.query)). Proper application of [`mysqli_stmt::store_result`](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt.store_result) may fix the problem.

Note that you shouldn't need to call `mysqli::stmt_init()`, which is present (as `mysqli_stmt_init`) to support procedural programming. Instead, you can use [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare).