# MySQL PreparedStatement Caveats

Tags: c++, mysql, resources, database-connection

I have a long-lived C++ program that executes a variety of SQL statements against a MySQL database.  I'm currently using a bunch of static sql::PreparedStatement *'s created (once) in each function that needs to SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE, and then they're re-bound and re-executed over and over again.  This works well, but I'm wondering about server and program resource usage:

- Where does each PreparedStatement store its info (client/server/both?)
- Do I have to worry about one PreparedStatement going bad, but the rest are OK?
- Should I refresh/recreate PreparedStatements occasionally?
- Do open but idle PreparedStatements tie up significant DB resources between uses?
- Is there a better way to handle DB activity in a program that needs to execute 20-30 different types of queries, when the queries happen occasionally and not in any particular order?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each prepared statement is parsed, optimized and stored in the database session, so it does take up resources while it is active and there is a max number of prepared statements per session.
The resources taken vary with the DB engine and the driver.
Depending on what exactly your prepared statements do and how frequently they are bound to variables and executed, and how simple or complex they are, you may want to look into implementing at least some of them using stored procedures instead.

For max_prepared statement_count reference is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_prepared_stmt_count).

For monitoring how much memory a prepared statement uses, you might want to run a little test: get the free memory your process sees before preparing a statement, then get it again after preparing, to see how much that statement uses, and one more time after closing the statement to see if everything is freed.

This will work before you execute the statement, because the amount of data returned may vary and will affect the total free memory for your process in the intermediate measuring step.

Also, you may want to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039151/problem-with-multiple-prepared-statements), and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

Comment: Thanks, that's useful info.  Do you have (or know where to find) approximate numbers for memory usage or max prepared statements per session?  If I'm well below the limits, I won't bother designing some complicated framework for this, but if I'm close, I might as well bite the bullet now.  (All the statements are pretty simple -- INSERTs or UPDATEs or single-table SELECTs. Nothing that should make the DB work very hard, except that sometimes a lot of rows might be returned.)

Comment: The max_prepared_statement_count config item is very reassuring (especially since it's a server-wide value).  I know what sort of utilization my server should see, and my expected number of PreparedStatements is well under 16k.  I'll poke around with memory instrumentation, but really, unless a PreparedStatement is allocating many megabytes (which seems really unlikely) I'm not going to have any trouble there.  Thanks again!

Comment: The internal memory allocated for a prepared statement is minimal compared to the allocation for a retrieved dataset, so I think you are ok there. Basically, the client-side allocation is just a basic structure that identifies the specific prep. statement on the server for the current session, and carries some more things like status, current state, etc. The real allocation is server-side, but still not a large one just for the statement. However, prepared statements can cause memory leaks on some servers, if not closed.